# Bare bones Facebook integration demo app

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

So I just started looking into integrating FB into my app and whipped up this little test app. I wanted to have a bare bones app without all of the bs that's in the Hackbook demo app. Basically, it's overly complicated for what I want.

The problem is that something I'm doing isn't working. My app tries to authenticate with FB, but doesn't return auth tokens. Something else that I noticed is that...

1. If I have the facebook app installed... it switches to it, shows a white loading screen for a second, then dismisses it and pops back to my app.
2. If the facebook app isn't installed... it will open in safari and actually show the app approval window, let me login and then it pops back to my app.

Both ways fail with getting and storing the auth tokens however.

What the heck am I doing wrong? Would someone mind seeing if this code works for them?

Full source here: Deleted.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Oh I guess I should mention that this was built on 10.7 with XCode 4.3.3 for iOS => 5.0 and uses ARC.

Comment: I just read on another site that the FB sdk has issues with ARC. Does anyone know if that's true? If so, what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Facebook just updated their SDK which now includes some simplified example apps. Much better than just hackbook.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like you don't have your app registered in the Facebook developer portal.

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: I do. But I might have hosed something. I can even get it to auth (on the FB side) if I don't have the FB app installed. But it still doesn't work on my apps side either way. Is there something in their settings that can hose things? I enabled desktop native app and that it uses SSO.

Comment: I should also mention that my app_id works from within Hackbook.